# XNA click object determining in scene

Tags: xna, click, collision

I am trying to write an XNA game. But I am new. I want to determine the top-most object in the scene. In rectangle form, when two rectangles intersect on the screen, I want to click on the top-most one. But I don't know how I can detect the top-most object from the scene.
Can anybody help me? Is there a method for that?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what method you are using to draw them.

- If you're use `SpriteSortMode.Deferred` mode you draw them in the order the `SpriteBatch.Draw` is called. In this way you know which object is top-most. To achieve that you need to check every object you have in a list, an array or whatever, the first (or the last, it depends on how you've managed your structure) element's `Rectangle` collider that contains your click will be the top-most object. Once you've found it you need to `break` the cycle that is "sweeping" your list/array, in order to detect only that click.
- If you're using `SpriteSortMode.BackToFront` or `FrontToBack` it's a bit harder to know.

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx).

**UPDATE**

When you draw your objects with `Deferred` mode, and they "collides" you know for sure that the last one that has been drawn is the top-most.
If you are using a list you have to do something like this:

```cs
for (int i = spriteList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (spriteList[i].collisionRect.Contains(touch))
    {
        topMostSprite = spriteList[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I searched for this method. But let me undderstand that. spritebatch.Begin() methods draw the objects in the drawing order. What's the advantage of spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend). And how cna I get the last drawing object properties. It returns a list or something. And sorry for the misunderstanding. I am a new at this.

Comment: If you use `SpriteBatch.Begin` without any parameters you are using the default mode `SpriteSortMode.Deferred`, that is easier to understand, imho. The advantage is that, as MSDN says, "allows Draw calls to two or more instances of `SpriteBatch` without introducing conflicting graphics device settings."

Comment: And for the list of drawing object, YOU have to manage them in a list or an array when you draw them, I don't know how your code is.

Comment: spriteBatch.Draw(b2, rect1, Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(b1, rect2, Color.White);   I am drawing my objects like that. Lets assume I am holding the objects List L in order rect2, rect1. If ı know the last drawing object  ı can scan my list and put a click properties on it. But how can ı get the last object from SpriteBatch? What is the method for that?

Comment: thank you for the answer. But for sure, I am seeting the elements of spriteList am I? But I am adding them in random order. But ı wanna get a ordered by depth. How can ı do that?

Comment: If you add them in random order you should know that List.Add method adds an object at the end of the list. So if you draw each element of your list starting by the first one you will have the first one as bottom-most and the last one as the top-most.

Comment: Thank you. I think, different types of elements. Thank you for the answer.